# Cron executed python script runs but does not update sqlite db

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu, cron

My python script (creates if needed) and inserts one row into an sqlite database. It works perfectly when run manually, but not when run by cron. When run by cron it will create the db file, without a schema, and also not insert the row.

Additionally, the command is set in my normal user's crontab, but the empty db file is owned by root.

This is the line in my crontab:

```
0/3 * * * * /home/ubuntu/fullstack/scrape.py
```

And this is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#file scrape.py

import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import time
import sqlite3

from datetime import timedelta

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.ihackernews.com/page')
res = response.read()
date = response.info()['date']
#                                       Sun, 19 Oct 2014 17:58:01 GMT
datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
datetime = datetime - timedelta(hours=5)
timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.timetuple()))
response.close()
res = json.loads(res)

title = res['items'][0]['title']
url = res['items'][0]['url']
points = res['items'][0]['points']



db = sqlite3.connect('/home/ubuntu/fullstack/interval_data.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE, title TEXT, url TEXT, points INTEGER, timestamp INTEGER, datetime TEXT);
''')
db.commit()

cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO data(title, url, points, timestamp, datetime)
    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);''', (title, url, points, timestamp, datetime.strftime('%d %b %Y, %I:%M %p %z')))
db.commit()




db.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and it seems to work fine for me.  A few things:

1. Make sure you are doing `crontab -e` to edit your crontab, not `sudo crontab -e`.
2. Make sure the python file is executable with `chmod +x /home/ubuntu/fullstack/scrape.py`.

Also, `0/3 * * * *` looks a bit odd to me, though I admit my knowledge of cron syntax is a bit iffy.  The `/3` says "take every third", but the 0 indicates to do it at the top of every hour.  Are you trying to do it every three hours (`* */3 * * *`)?  Every three minutes (`*/3 * * * *`)?

Comment: Every three minutes. It's only set that frequently to speed up debugging. The file is executable and yes, it's in the "ubuntu" user's crontab.

Comment: Can you try editing the job to `*/3` from `0/3`?  Also, delete the db file, or manually change ownership to the ubuntu user.  See if that helps at all.  All I can say is that I'm using Python 2.7.6 on a clean Xubuntu install.  I copied your script (changing only the name of the user), set the user's crontab with `*/3` instead of `0/3`, made the file executable and it works.  Job runs, DB file is created or edited properly and the ownership is correct.

Comment: Ok, so as a partial solution I deleted the db, manually ran the script, and then deleted the first row. So I was left with a db that has a schema, but no rows, and it's now updating correctly. So technically it's working now, but I still don't know what the problem was.